# 2019 Jetta - How to Remove Grille?

Tags: vw, jetta, body-work, body

I just purchased a 2019 VW Jetta, and would like to remove the grille. (The car has a wimpy horn, and removing the grill would allow access to the space between it and the radiator/AC condenser, perfect for a pair of Fiamms).

The grille is one piece, made of both metal and plastic elements, and about 10" high. Its top edge fastens with four screws to the frame around the radiator/AC condenser. Remove those four screws and the grille loosens at the top, but is still fastened on each side at the bottom. Having looked carefully, and pulled and twisted and lifted as much as I dare, I am unable to discover how it's fastened, or how to release it.

The owner's manual provides no guidance, and the car is too new for any shop manuals to have appeared in the aftermarket.

I'd be grateful for any guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sprang for one of those "consult with an expect mechanic" sites, and was advised that the grille is clipped to the bumper underneath it, and that the grille cannot be removed separately. Grille removal is accomplished by removing the bumper, which also requires removing one or both of the under-engine covers as well as the screws that fasten the covers to the liners in the front wheel wells.

Comment: Finally got VW's shop manual for the car. It confirms that removing the grille requires prior removal of the bumper. I hit the checkmark as the question is answered correctly.